# What am I doing wrong in this Linear Algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

The question, which is in my Linear Algebra textbook (no answer is provided), goes as follows:

> Let $W=\text{span}\{v_1= [2,2,-2,0]^T, \hspace{.2cm}v_2=[0, 1, 1, -1]^T, \hspace{.2cm} v_3=[1,1,2,-4]^T\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ endowed with the usual Euclidean inner product.

- Find the angle between the vectors $v_1, v_2$ and $v_1, v_3$. What do you observe on where $v_1$ belongs?

I calculate: For $v_1, v_2: \hspace{.2cm} \cos{\theta}=\displaystyle\frac{v_1^Tv_2}{||v_1|| \cdot ||v_2||}=0\Rightarrow \theta=\pi/2$ and the same for $v_1, v_3.$ So, does $v_1$ lie on the same line as the other two vectors?

- Find an orthonormal basis for $W$.

I use the Gram-Schmidt process and find the basis $B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
\displaystyle - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
\displaystyle - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{195}}{65} \\
\displaystyle\frac{4\sqrt{195}}{195} \\
\displaystyle\frac{7\sqrt{195}}{195} \\
\displaystyle\frac{11\sqrt{195}}{195}
\end{bmatrix} \right\}$. Is there a better basis?

- Find an orthonormal basis for the orthogonal complement $W^{\perp}$ of $W$.

I just calculated the basis of the null space which I found to be $B_{W^{\perp}}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{5}{3} \\
\displaystyle - \frac{1}{3} \\
\displaystyle\frac{4}{3} \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

- Find the orthogonal projection of the vector $u=(1, -1, 1, 1)$ on $W$ and $W^{\perp}$

Is this not the sum of the orthogonal projections of $u$ onto all of the vectors of $W$ and $W^{\perp}$?

I am so sorry for writing such a long exercise, but I would appreciate help with these, by either pointing out my mistakes or providing your own solution (particularly on that last one). It is just that it's the first exam I'm taking and I'm nervous that I need to know what I am doing.

Comment: if the cosine is $0$ the angle is $\pi/2+k \pi$, not $0$. You have $v_1 \perp v_2$ and $v_1 \perp v_3$ but not $v_2 \perp v_3$.

Comment: the angle between 2 and 3 is not  $cos(\theta) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

The vector $v_1$ is orthogonal to both $v_2$ and $v_3$. So, $v_1$ belongs to the plane orthogonal to $v_2$ and to $v_3$. On the other hand, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are not orthogonal.

When I apply the Gramm-Schmidt process to $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, what I get is the basis $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ equal to$$\left\{\left[\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},-\frac1{\sqrt3},0\right]^T,\left[0,\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},-\frac1{\sqrt3}\right]^T,\left[\frac3{\sqrt{51}},-\frac4{\sqrt{51}},-\frac1{\sqrt{51}},-\frac5{\sqrt{51}}\right]^T\right\}.$$On the other hand, the second and third vectors of the basis that you got are not orthogonal.

The orthogonal projection of $u$ on $W$ is$$(u.w_1)w_1+(u.w_2)w_2+(u.w_3)w_3=\left[-\frac{14}{51},-\frac{38}{51},-\frac{1}{51},\frac{12}{51}\right]^T.$$And the orthogonal projection of $u$ on $W^\perp$ is$$u-\left[-\frac{14}{51},-\frac{38}{51},-\frac{1}{51},\frac{12}{51}\right]^T=\left[\frac{65}{51},-\frac{13}{51},\frac{52}{51},\frac{39}{51}\right]^T.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the orthogonal projections be column vectors?

Comment: @PeterAllen Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No problem, man.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, how do you subtract a column vector from a row vector in the last expression?

Comment: I assumed that $u=[1,-1,1,1]^T$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Actually, is there a need to do so? Instead of decomposing it, can't you take the dot product again but after finding an orthonormal basis for $W^{\perp}$? If OP used the Gram-Schmidt process on the single column vector they have, they would be left with an orthonormal basis. But I am assuming this is already known. Nothing seems to change anyway but just to be sure.

Comment: @PeterAllen Yes, that works. But I think that my method is simpler.